# AJAX/PHP Error on showing "Success": Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: php, ajax, lightbox

I need help. I build a "search" form for search the database and send it via AJAX. The problem is, the content is delivered and the result is also beeing shown in Google Chrome Web Develeloper Tools under Requests -> Preview, but not on screen. The result is beeing arrived.

But here comes the error when i want to display the result on screen with lightbox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBmZ4.png

My codes, 
**jQuery POST AJAX**

```
function submitDetailsForm() {
 $('#searchit').submit(function() {
        var content = $("#searchit_input").val();
        var dataString = 'content='+ content;
        if(content == '') { alert("Nothing here."); } else {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/search.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
             $.lightbox("/ajax/search.php", {
    'width'       : 610,
    'height'      : 458,
    'autoresize'  : true
  });;
            }

            });
            }       
        return false;   
    });
}
```

**SEARCH.php**

```
<?php
$Results = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_title LIKE '%$content%' AND keywords LIKE '%$content%' AND topstory != '' ORDER BY post_modified DESC LIMIT 8"); 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($Results) < 1) {    

        echo "Nothing found.."; 
    } else {


        while($Show = $Results->fetch_object()) {
        $Title =  $Show->post_title; 
        $Topstory = $Show->topstory;
        $Description = $Show->longdesc;
        $id = $Show->ID;




?>
hi
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: have you included the js file for lightbox?

Comment: Are you calling `submitDetailsForm` before it is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not displaying the `result` onscreen with lightbox.  You're not using the `result` at all.  Odds are that's where your issue is coming in.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/search.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        // you need to actually do something with `result` in here to
        // actually use the result of your ajax call.
    }
});
```

You don't indicate which lightbox plugin you're using, so I don't know how it should work, but it's a fair bet you don't have it set up to do what you want.